# Finding counterexamples and proving a transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Can someone please explain instances where $ f^{-1} (f (A)) \not = A $ and $f (f^{-1}(B)) \not = B$ if $ f:X \rightarrow Y $ and $ A$is a subset of X and B is a subset of Y? I can't think of when this would be true.

I also have the following problem, that I am hoping someone could link me to a source to explain it or do so here:

Prove that the transformation T from $\mathbb {R}^m $ to $\mathbb {R}^n $ is linear if and only if $ T (rx+y)=rT (x)+T (y) $ for $x, y \in \mathbb {R}$ and scalars $ r $.

I'm not sure I understand what transformations entail, it seems like this is just a result of distribution.

Comment: What definition of a linear transformation are you using?

Comment: Is that meant to say $x,y\in \mathbb R^m$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a constant function, so for some $y \in Y$, we have $f(x) = y$ for all $x \in X$. Pick a point $x \in X$, and let $A = \{x\}$. Then $f(A) = \{y\}$, and $f^{-1}(f(A)) = f^{-1}(\{y\}) = X$. So if $X$ has more than one point, then $A$ is properly contained in $f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Next, let $B = Y$, with $f$ as in the previous paragraph. Then $f^{-1}(B) = X$, and $f(f^{-1}(B)) = f(X) = \{y\}$. So if $B=Y$ contains more than one point, then $f(f^{-1}(B))$ is properly contained in $B$.

For the linear transformation question, first suppose that $T$ is linear. By definition, $T(rx + sy) = rT(x) + sT(y)$ for all scalars $r,s$ and all vectors $x,y$. Taking the special case $s=1$ shows that $T(rx + y) = rT(x) + T(y)$.

Conversely, suppose that $T(rx + y) = rT(x) + T(y)$ for every scalar $r$ and all vectors $x,y$. Let $s$ be any scalar. Then $T(rx + sy) = rT(x) + T(sy) = rT(x) + T(sy + 0) = rT(x) + sT(y) + T(0)$, so it suffices to show that $T(0) = 0$. But we can easily see this by taking $r=1$ and $x=y=0$. In this case, $T(0) = T(rx+y) = rT(x) + T(y) = T(0) + T(0)$. Subtracting $T(0)$ from both sides gives us $T(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add a little bit to help your intuition of a linear transformation. A transformation T is analogous to a function in that it is a rule that tells you what vector out you will get given some input vector. I think the term transformation can be understood in terms of a geometric picture. Picture some object like a box in the cartesian plane, being formed by a set of points. If you apply a transformation on this box like multiplying each the x component of each vector by some scalar c, you will stretch the box in the x direction.

It turns out that a linear transformation can always be represented by a matrix, so this is probably why you imagine it as just a consequence of distribution. But I think it is good to keep in mind that a transformation is simply a rule that tells you what to do with a given vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have written

1) a *definition* of the inverse map: $f^{-1}\circ f=\operatorname{id}$

2) a *definition* of a linear map $T (rx+y)=rT (x)+T (y)$